# Trouble with "next" on search results page

Tags: html

I have been trying to get the next button to work for hours now. Somehow, when the next button is clicked, it searches a blank field. I am not sure how this is happening or how to fix it.

```
<ul>
  <!--disables buttons if there is only one page-->
  {{if or (le .MaxPage 1) (eq .PageNum 0)}}
  <li>
    {{if and (ne .MaxPage 0) (ne .PageNum 0)}}
    <h5>Page {{.PageNum}} of {{.MaxPage}}</h5> {{end}}
  </li>
  <li>
    {{if not (or (.Errors.Contains .Constants.NoSearch) (.Errors.Contains .Constants.NoResults))}}
    <input class="button" type="button" name="prev_next" value="prev" disabled> |
    <input class="button" type="button" name="prev_next" value="next" disabled> |
    <input disabled class="button" type="submit" name="prev_next" value="all">
    {{end}}
  </li>
  {{else}}
  <li>
    <form method="GET">
      <h5>Page {{.PageNum}} of {{.MaxPage}}</h5>
      <input type="hidden" name="curr_page" value="{{.PageNum}}">
      <input type="text" name="type" {{if ASearch .PageID}}value="adv"{{else}}value=""{{end}} hidden>
  </li>
  <li>
    <!--if this is the first page-->
    {{if eq .PageNum 1}}
    <input class="button" type="button" name="prev_next" value="prev" disabled> |
    {{else}}
<input class="button" type="submit" name="prev_next" value="prev"> |
    {{end}}
    <!--if this is the last page-->
    {{if eq .PageNum .MaxPage}}
    <input class="button" type="button" name="prev_next" value="next" disabled> |
    {{else}}
<input class="button" type="submit" name="prev_next" value="next"> |
    {{end}}
    {{if gt .MaxPage 1}}
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="prev_next" value="all">
    {{else}}
<input disabled class="button" type="submit" name="prev_next" value="all">
    {{end}}
    </form>
  </li>
  {{end}}
</ul>
```

The page is supposed to determine which page we are on and then display a certain array of items depending on the page number. However, this is not happening.

I tried setting breakpoints at it, but that was not workign and would just skip when I clicked next. Any idea what is happening?

Comment: Why don't you use setOnClickListener()

Comment: I tried the mouse click event listener in chrome dev tools, but that didn't work either

Comment: it looks like you're doing this on the backend {{}}  which seems odd to me.  Why not control the next button through javascript?

Comment: Hm. I was brought onto the project and am trying to fix other people's code. Do you think I can just change the page number on the next click then via javascript? It looks  they tried to use the backend to store cookies